# How do i make one div adjustable while other succeeding column fixed?

Tags: html, css

Help newbie in div for php or html without using css or table.

Trying to do this 4 x column, 2 x row using div with the following behavior

```
 // [.....adjustable....][fixed][fixed][fixed]
 // [.....adjustable....][fixed][fixed][fixed]
```

Below are my codes----------------------------------------

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="get">

<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; ">
  <div id="left" style="position:relative;float:left;width:68%;"> left </div>
  <div id="right" style="float:left;width:13%;"> Name: </div>
  <div id="right2" style="float:left;width:13%;"> Age: </div>
  <div id="right3" style="float:left;width:6%;"></div>   
</div>

<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; ">
  <div id="left2" style="position:relative;float:left;width:68%;"> left2 </div>
  <div id="right4" style="float:left;width:13%;">  <input type="text" name="name"></div>
  <div id="right5" style="float:left;width:13%;">  <input type="text" name="age"></div>
  <div id="right6" style="float:left;width:6%;"> <input name="submit" type="submit"></div>
</div>
```

The 68% is equal to 860 pxl on my screen. It should change if it goes to other screen resolution. I tried making the 68% to 100% and the other div with id=right to style="position:fixed..." but it just mess up and puts everything on left side.

Comment: Different elements cannot have the same id. Use a class instead. It is discouraged to use inline style for these kind of things. `width:150` is an invalid style, as it misses a unit (px, em, %). Some browsers might 'correct' it to px, and others might ignore it.

Comment: thanks, i'll correct my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of accomplishing this, is by using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`, to style divs as a table, without using an actual table:

[Example on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iminop/1/). See [display on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

I'll add both the CSS version and the, discouraged, inline style version to this post:

**CSS version**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">ASDF</div>
  <div class="right">asdf</div>
  <div class="right">asdf</div>
  <div class="right">asdf</div>
</div>
```

With CSS:

```
.parent {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  width: auto;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  display: table-cell;
}

.right {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px dotted green;
}
```

**Inline style version**

```
<div style="display: table; width: 100%;">
  <div style="display: table-cell;">ASDF</div>
  <div style="display: table-cell; width: 150px;">asdf</div>
  <div style="display: table-cell; width: 150px;">asdf</div>
  <div style="display: table-cell; width: 150px;">asdf</div>
</div>
```